# Enable magento extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

All extensions are disabled from the admin panel and the admin panel is empty.

How to enable it again? 
In the `app/etc/modules` all are set as **active=true**

So is there a way to enable it from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly enable it from database if its already enabled it from module xmls.

Goto **core_config_data** and search run the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%advanced/modules_disable_output%'
```

This will returns all the modules enabled or disabled from admin. If value is **0** then its **enabled** and if value is **1** then its **disabled**. You can change the values according to your requirement.

Delete the cache and session directory from var directory and test if everything works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, It helped me to solve the issue. Thank You.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding!